# How to check value of radio button in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: radio-button, visual-c++-6, checked

I recently took over a project at work that has a GUI written in Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0, which I am not familiar with. The original developer of the GUI is no longer with us, and nobody else here is familiar with Visual C++ 6.0. The MSDN collection was apparently never installed, and we are missing our installation material. On top of that, it appears Microsoft's [documentation site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcedit98/HTML/vcstartpage.asp) is down.

Fortunately, I don't have to do much work with the GUI. All I need to know right now is how to determine if a radio button is checked. Could someone please instruct me?

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly mentioned in the Microsoft's documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) about the radio button checked property. Hope this helps.

Comment: Which is awesome... except that he specified VC++ 6.0, in which case that .Net info is rather irrelevant. :(

Comment: Chris Krycho is correct; VS6 and VS.NET are entirely different animals.